# Emph or morekeywords does not show any effect

Tags: listings

I would like a number of selected (sub-)strings to become highlighted as keywords (or emphasized):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}


\lstdefinestyle{MyStyle} {
    boxpos=c,%
    breaklines=true,%
    showlines=false,%
    numbers=left,   %numbers=none,%
    numberstyle=\tiny,%
    firstnumber=1,%
    numbersep=5pt,%
    showstringspaces=false,%
    frame=none,%frame=single,%
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\underline,%
    captionpos=b, %
    literate={<-}{{$\leftarrow{}$}}2,
    rangeprefix=\#\/\/\ ,
    rangesuffix=\ \/\/}

\begin{filecontents*}{src.code}
#// start //
A  <- `A` 'a' a:B;
B  <- `B` 'b' b:<alnum>;
#// end //
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\lstset{includerangemarker=false,
  style=MyStyle}
\lstinputlisting[linerange=start-end,alsoletter={:},morekeywords={A,B,a:,b:}]{src.code}

\end{document}
```

I simply fail to get this right. While, in the example, occurrences of "A", "B", "b:" get marked (underlined) as exptected, "a:" is not. I would appreciate some hints.

Comment: I should add: I want the letters between grave accents to be highlighted, as well as the prefixes "a:" and "b:".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In lisings, a keyword is always a complete word, so a maximal sequence of letters. After `alsoletter={:}`, `a:B` is a sequence of letters which is not a keyword, so it is no highlighted as a keyword.
You can fix this by avoiding `alsoletter={:}`, then `:` is no longer a letter, so it can be used to separate words. Of course, thien you can no longer use `morekeywords={a:,b:}`.
The `\listings` package has a special key `otherkeywords` for this purpose: `otherkeywords` contains keywords which do contain non-letters.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{filecontents*}{src.code}
#// start //
A  <- `A` 'a' a:B;
B  <- `B` 'b' b:<alnum>;
#// end //
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[keywordstyle=\underline,morekeywords={A,B,a:,b:},otherkeywords={a:,b:}]{src.code}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A clear and consise answer, much appreciated! I wanted to fix two typos as beauty spots, but they are too minor: `lisings` -> `listings`, `thien` -> `then` ;)